# Social Engine Editing drop down options

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, socialengine

I am using a 3rd party developed plugin.
Advanced Activity Feeds

On a search widget we have a drop down which has all of my profile types.
I wish for this widget to show certain profile types.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom code. You can get the particular profile type by level_id.